# why the tf.Session() returns a wrong result?

Tags: tensorflow

I'm a newbie to tensorflow and met the problem below. I'm very thankful for your answer.

```python
a = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
b = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
adder_node = a + b  

print(sess.run(adder_node, {a: 3, b:4.5}))
```

**then the result is 0.0.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How exactly did you define `sess`?

I just ran your code within a `tf.Session()` context and it worked:

```python
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.Session() as sess:
    a = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
    b = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
    adder_node = a + b  

    print(sess.run(adder_node, {a: 3, b: 4.5}))
```

Output: `7.5`

Comment: Thank you for your help.I defined 'tf.Session()' as 'sess',and repeated the code . The result is 7.5.And your  code style is more beautiful .

Answer (score 1):

It can be a memory problem.

If you're using notebooks, try stopping these notebooks.

If you're using Docker-Nvidia, just try restarting the container:

```
nvidia-docker stop <container-name>
```

And then restart:

```
nvidia-docker start <container-name>
```